# Passing function name to Func delegate

Tags: c#, .net

I have a very specific situation. I need to accept a function name from user and pass this function name (We already know that this function exists) to another method that handles function calls. This method is named `RunMethod` and it accepts `Func<string, string> method`.

I know that I can use something like:

```
string methodName = "methodName";
MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
mi.Invoke(this, null);
```

But in this case I would have to change the `RunMethod` method and it's **not an option** because of existing code using it.

**So how do I pass a string as method name to another method that accepts `Func<string, string>`?**

A simplified implementation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pr = new Program();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a method name: ");

    // user enters a method name
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // Can accept Method1 or Method2 as parameter
    // But we need to pass the "input"
    RunMethod(Method1);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void RunMethod(Func<string, string> method)
{
    Console.WriteLine(method("John Doe"));
}

static string Method1(string name)
{
    return "method 1 called : " + name;
}

static string Method2(string name)
{
    return "method 2 called : " + name;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So how do I pass a string as method name to another method that accepts `Func<string, string>`?

You don't - you create a `Func<string, string>` instead. You can do that with [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var method = GetType().GetMethod(...);
var func = (Func<string, string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<string, string>), method);
RunMethod(func);
```

Note that this assumes you've already figured out how to get the method appropriately - in your sample code, your methods are private so you'd need to pass `BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic` into the `GetMethod` call.

Complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a method name: ");

        // user enters a method name
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod(input,
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var func = (Func<string, string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Func<string, string>), method);
        RunMethod(func);
    }

    static void RunMethod(Func<string, string> method)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(method("John Doe"));
    }

    static string Method1(string name)
    {
        return "method 1 called : " + name;
    }

    static string Method2(string name)
    {
        return "method 2 called : " + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3185569: Why would it throw an `ArgumentException`?

Comment: In my case it would be `pr.GetType().GetMethod(input);` and it's null.

Comment: @VSG24: Well that's the first thing to fix then - but that's got nothing to do with converting a `MethodInfo` into a `Func`, it's a matter of calling `GetMethod` appropriately.

Comment: Am I not calling it appropriately?

Comment: @user3185569: But that's not what the code does. It creates a `Func<string, string>` from the `MethodInfo` using `CreateDelegate`, and passes *that* into the method.

Comment: Those flags worked! It works correctly and as expected.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry. You're Right. My mistake.

Comment: @user3185569: Because unlike the methods shown in the OP's sample code, your method is a `void` method with no parameters.